# Meaning of "Don't be a dog in a blanket"

Tags: phrases, expressions

As a child, my father (born and raised in the north-west of England) used to occasionally admonish one of us by saying "Don't be a dog in a blanket". I've never exactly understood the meaning of the phrase other than I remember it was usually used in the context of protecting some item in a selfish and sullen manner.

Has anyone else heard this phrase before and could they provide further context and meaning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The traditional saying/idiom is "a dog in a **manger**": it has been attributed to (and popularised by) Aesop's fables.

It is discussed in [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dog_in_the_Manger) and [theidioms.com](https://www.theidioms.com/dog-in-the-manger/)

> The short form of the fable as cited by Laura Gibbs is: "There was a dog lying in a manger who did not eat the grain, but who nevertheless prevented the horse from being able to eat anything either."
>
> The story was first glossed in the 1st century CE lexicon of Diogenianus as "The dog in the manger, concerning those who neither themselves use nor allow others to use: Insofar as the dog neither itself eats the barleycorns, nor allows the horse to"

Your father had the saying wrong... :)

Comment: Thank you, that has cleared up a small mystery in my mind :) I think it is my memory that has corrupted the phrase over the decades (or the child did not understand what a manger was and substituted a familiar word) and why it made even less sense to me now.

Comment: @avenmore, perhaps your father had simply adapted the phrase to a modern context, since few urban folk know what a *manger* is unless they've looked up this specific phrase. If a house dog is protecting anything, it's likely to be a bone from the comfort of its bed blanket, not the food in a manger. Also, some dogs can be stroppy and unapproachable when inside their bed blankets, particularly if they are tired and disturbed awake, or have retired there to sulk about other events.